# How can I find exact occurences of a string in another string in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, string-matching, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have one column (coming from google forms) containing a comma-separated list of names and I want to check if a specific name is included in this list.

There are several functions (match, search, find, etc.), I tried and it kind of worked up to a certain point. The problem arises as soon as the list contains a name like "Carolin" and the name that I want to check is "Caro".

Then it always returns "true" which is logically correct because the string "Carolin" obviously contains the string "Caro".

In my case, I want to distinguish between "Carolin" and "Caro" as shown in the example. How can I do that?

```
names                            | name to check   | expected result
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Michael, Carolin, John, Jane     | John            | True
Michael, Carolin, John, Jane     | Sarah           | False
Michael, Carolin, John, Jane     | Carolin         | True
Michael, Carolin, John, Jane     | Caro            | False
Michael, Carolin, John, Jane R.  | Jane R.         | True
Michael, Carolin, John, Jane R.  | Jane            | False
```

Edit: Added two lines in the example. I forgot about another special case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXMATCH(JOIN( ,
 REGEXMATCH(TRIM(SPLIT(A1, ",")), "^"&B1&"$")), "T")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This formula does what I want, however, I think the formula I posted in my answer is much shorter. What is the advantage / disadvantage of arrayformula?

Comment: the advantage is that you don't need to drag down formula eg. have 1 formula per row. you just paste it in the first cell and it will auto calculate the rest like in the image

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A2,"\b"&B2&"\b")
```

[REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292). `\b` denotes an ASCII word boundary.

Comment: Yeah thanks, this works. But I think I forgot another special case when "Alex R." appears in names, name to check is "Alex", I expect the result to be False. Let me adapt my question.

Comment: I think I found the solution: `=REGEXMATCH(A2, B2(,|$))`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is searching for a short solution, I found that this formula works:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A2,B2&"(,|$)")
```